# Django- Template not found

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I can't seem to get my delete, edit and add review functionality working. The errors come as soon as I try to navigate to the urls I have set up. When I try and add a new review using my link on the reviews page I get the below message:

TemplateDoesNotExist at /reviews/add

I don't understand why because I have linked the url above to the template, which I have created.

The issue I have with my edit/delete views is that the url it searches for when I click the button is just **/edit/** or **/delete/** rather than **reviews/edit/int:pk** or **reviews/delete/int:pk** as per my urls.

I have pasted my code below, any help would be much appreciated! I have the feeling I am going to kick myself when I realise!

reviews.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid home-container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mt-4">
            <h2><strong>Reviews</strong></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% for review in reviews %}
    <hr class="hr-1">
    <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">{{ review.title }}</h2>
            <p class="lead">{{ review.content }}</p>
            <div class="row justify-content-between mx-1">
                <p>By: {{ review.user }}</p>
                <p>Created on: {{ review.created }}</p>
                <p>Last Updated: {{ review.updated }}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Add user authentication if -->
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="edit/{{ review.id }}" class="mx-2">
                    <button class="positive-button mb-2">Edit</button></a>
                <a href="delete/{{ review.id }}" class="mx-2 mb-2">
                    <button class="negative-button">Delete</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center py-4">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'home:add_review' %}">
                <button class="positive-button-lg">Add a review</button>
            </a>
            {% else %}
            <p>If you would like to add your own review, please login or sign up if you haven't already!</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

add_review.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto text-center p-3">
            <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
                {{ review_form }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Reviews
from .forms import ReviewForm


def home(request):
    ''' Returns the home page.'''
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')


def reviews(request):
    ''' Returns the reviews page.'''

    serialized_reviews = []

    reviews = Reviews.objects.all()

    for review in reviews:
        serialized_reviews.append({
            "title": review.title,
            "content": review.content,
            "user": review.user,
            "created": review.created,
            "updated": review.updated,
        })

    context = {
        "reviews": serialized_reviews
        }
    print(serialized_reviews)
    return render(request, 'home/reviews.html', context)


class AddReview(View):
    '''View which allows the user to add a new review.'''

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        review = Reviews
        review_form = ReviewForm
             
        context = {
            'review': review,
            'review_form': review_form,
            'user': review.user,
            'title': review.title,
            'content': review.content,
        }
        return render(request, 'add_review.html', context)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        review_form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)

        if review_form.is_valid():
            obj = review_form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            
        return redirect("home:reviews")


class DeleteReview(DeleteView):
    '''View which allows the user to delete the selected review.'''
    model = Reviews
    template_name = 'delete_review.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('reviews')


class EditReview(UpdateView):
    '''View which allows the user to edit the selected review.'''
    model = Reviews
    template_name = 'edit_review.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content']
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('reviews', views.reviews, name='reviews'),
    path('reviews/add', views.AddReview.as_view(), name='add_review'),
    path('reviews/delete/<int:pk>', views.DeleteReview.as_view(), name='delete_review'),
    path('reviews/edit/<int:pk>', views.EditReview.as_view(), name='edit_review'),
]
```

Comment: see the difference `return render(request, 'add_review.html', context)` vs `return render(request, 'home/reviews.html', context)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're writing in your urls the wrong way, like this below your div text-center:

```
<a href="edit/{{ review.id }}" class="mx-2">
```

It [should be](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'yourappname:edit' review.id %}">
```

Comment: No no, <a href="edit/{{review.id}}"> This is also a correct way

Comment: @ManojTolagekar Django-way is url reversion. hardcoding paths is a misconception. Hardcoded url violates DRY, url reversion besides a) DRY b) confirms that url pattern exists thus maps templates and urlpatterns c) validates number and order of parameters required by url pattern. So you don't have to guess whether you need `review` in front of the url or not, should pk be in the end of url or in the middle... in each and every template. so @JimmyFl0 has a good point and keeping it as OP stated originally is not the best choice and leads to more troubles than he already has.

Comment: Added link to docs to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is my app name, which is 'core'. Also, I forgot to add the content field to the model, but that is easily done, the form will just handle it as soon as you do the migration. (except on list.html)

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils import timezone

class Reviews(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now())
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from core.models import Reviews

class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from core.models import Reviews
from core.forms import ReviewsForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def list_reviews(request):
    reviews = Reviews.objects.all()

    context = {
        "reviews": reviews
        }
    return render(request, 'reviews/list.html', context)

def add_review(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/reviews/')
    else:
        form = ReviewsForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    return render(request, 'reviews/detail.html', context)

def edit_review(request, pk):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = Reviews.objects.get(id=pk)
            obj.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            obj.user = form.cleaned_data['user']
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/reviews/')
    else:
        obj = Reviews.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = ReviewsForm(instance=obj)

    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    return render(request, 'reviews/detail.html', context)

def delete_review(request, pk):
    obj = Reviews.objects.get(id=pk)
    obj.delete()
    return redirect('/reviews/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
import core.views as views

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('reviews/', views.list_reviews, name='list-reviews'),
    path('reviews/add', views.add_review, name='add-review'),
    path('reviews/edit/<int:pk>/', views.edit_review, name='edit-review'),
    path('reviews/delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete_review, name='delete-review'),
]
```

list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid home-container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mt-4">
            <h2><strong>Reviews</strong></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% for review in reviews %}
    <hr class="hr-1">
    <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">{{ review.title }}</h2>
            <p class="lead">{{ review.content }}</p>
            <div class="row justify-content-between mx-1">
                <p>By: {{ review.user }}</p>
                <p>Created on: {{ review.created_at }}</p>
                <p>Last Updated: {{ review.updated_at }}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Add user authentication if -->
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="{% url 'core:edit-review' pk=review.id %}" class="mx-2">
                    <button class="positive-button mb-2">Edit</button></a>
                <a href="{% url 'core:delete-review' pk=review.id %}"  class="mx-2 mb-2">
                    <button class="negative-button">Delete</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center py-4">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'core:add-review' %}">
                <button class="positive-button-lg">Add a review</button>
            </a>
            {% else %}
            <p>If you would like to add your own review, please login or sign up if you haven't already!</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto text-center p-3">
            <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;"> 
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table>                    
                    {{ form }}
                </table>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your urls, It is a `review/edit/<int:pk>`.
So you must add same thing in href tag.

Change this:

```
<a href="edit/{{ review.id }}"
```

To this:

```
<a href="review/edit/{{ review.id }}"
```

That's why you are getting that error

Comment: This gives me the same error, the url isn't pulling through the review ID with it for some reason

Comment: try adding forward slash in the begining of review. EX: <a href="/review/edit/{{ review.id }}"

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it, firstly the path in my add_review view was wrong, which I have amended and it now works (thanks Ivan).

I also was not actually bringing the ID through on my 'reviews' view in the first place, so when following the links on my edit and review buttons, it didn't know what I meant by 'id', as I hadn't specified what that was in the view context.

Thanks for the help all!